# 404 Not Found page displayed when accessing a lot of the Apache MINA links

Tags: java, network-programming, nio, apache-mina

I have to embed a network layer into my Java application in order to enable file transfer from a server to multiple client connections.

Having come to the conclusion that Java NIO would be the best option for this, I started looking for some existing NIO network frameworks.

I came across Apache MINA and started learning it. The problem is many of its links don't seem to be working anymore. For example, this link to the Apache MINA 2.0.7 API puts out a 404 Not Found page. [Apache MINA 2.0.7 API](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/overview-summary.html).

Could you please let me know what has happened to them and whether there are alternative links for them?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The website is underwork we will fix that asap !

as a workaround you will find everything there : http://apache.org/dist/mina/

Answer (score 2):

My fault : while reorganizing the full web site, I wrongly pointed to the bad download directory. It's now fixed, but it won't be visible until the mirrors are updated (so to speak, in a few hours).

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Side note : it's better to report such issue on the MINA users list, as we are not necessary watching stackoverflow (well, less frequenlty :)

Comment: I have posted a Jira ticket on this issue which is still reproducible - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-915

Comment: It should now work. I fixed those links 3 hours ago, and the pages will now propagate on the various mirror.

Comment: Sorry, I have been probably not specific enough, but it was not the download links that didn't work, but rather others related to the documentation and user guide. Are you able to access the link provided by me above? I am still unable to access it. Another example of a link that doesn't work is the [ClientSessionHandler](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/sumup/ClientSessionHandler.html) reffered to in the [Sample TCP Client](http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch2-basics/sample-tcp-client.html) section of the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation. But I found the way how to download Mina.
I noticed that link www.apache.org/dist/mina/2.0.7/apache-mina-2.0.7-bin.zip.md5 is reacheable.

So that, I changed link: http://mina.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/mina/2.0.7/apache-mina-2.0.7-src.zip
to
http://www.apache.org/dist/mina/2.0.7/apache-mina-2.0.7-src.zip

And wow, it works!

**UPDATE:**
BTW, all Mina links worked well 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Well, they most probably used to work, I started learning it this week though and I am just unhappy to see that a lot of the MINA related links of Apache don't work anymore. I have managed to download MINA and even establish a client-server connection with it. I find it very difficult now just studying it and accessing valuable documentation references.